# Regex - Match each line or nothing

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I have this `/([^\s](\-|\w)+\s(\d){1,2}[^\w\d\s])+/s` regex-expression in order to match this:

```
Name 11
Name-with-Seperators 22
Another Name 33
```

I want to validate that the input follows this format: Name, white-space, number, line-break

If it does not, it should not match. However I can only make it work to match something.
The input validation happens in Google Sheets, so I cannot split each line and test it separately easily.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try `^\w+(?:-\w+)*\s+\d{1,2}(?:(?:\r\n?|\n)\w+(?:-\w+)*\s+\d{1,2})*$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/5Ufqk2/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to match every line separately :
`/^[a-z\-]+\s\d+$/gim`

it matches at first, a group of letter with potential separators, then looks for a whitespace and a group of digits.

- g modifier is for the regex not to stop at the first match
- i modifier is for case insensitiveness
- m modifier is for multiline input

But if your goal is to match the whole thing as only one group that's either true or false you could go for something like :
`/^[a-z\-]+\s\d+(\n[a-z\-]+\s\d+)*\n$/i`

It assumes that each line even the last is ended by a newline. It does the same thing as the first one but after the first line it checks for between 0 and unlimited lines that follow the same pattern as the first one.